# How to mock an unit test for a delete bucket operation using boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, boto3

I'm using Python 2.7 and boto3 to interact with S3 buckets. So far so good!

What I'm trying to achieve now is an unit test for the delete bucket operation, but using mocked data, i.e., with no real interaction with the S3 storage.

For other unit tests throughout the project, I've used patches and boto3's Stubber successfully, but for some reason, I'm unable to find a way to use the same techniques to mock interactions using the [S3 resource](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource) and the [Bucket sub-resource](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ServiceResource.Bucket).

This is the snippet of code I want to unit test:

```
def delete_bucket(self, bucket_name):
    resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
    bucket.objects.all().delete()
    return bucket.delete()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html). With this, any method can be patched and the return value can be set:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
with patch('boto3.bucket.delete') as boto_delete_patch:
    boto_delete_patch.return_value = 'Return value'
    # Perform any action
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to mock a deletion of an object in the bucket and I had to mock the client:

```
from unittest import mock
def your_test():
    with mock.patch("boto3.client"):
        # Your code to test
```